# How to pass a parameter from login.jsp to pre login event file

Tags: java, liferay

I have created a hook by customizing portal.properties file as follows:-

```
login.events.pre=com.abhishek.CustomLoginAction
```

I want to retrieve the parameter named "login" from `/html/portlet/login/login.jsp` into the CustomLoginAction. I tried with the code as follows:-

```
public class CustomLoginAction extends Action{

  @Override
  public void run(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws ActionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("login parameter "+arg0.getParameter("login"));
  }
}
```

But I am getting the value of parameter as null even when I pass some parameter through the login form.It means if I am not wrong that I am not able to fetch the value passed through the form. So how to retrieve the parameter value?
Please help..Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a login event you can access the user through the request attributes:

```
User user = (User) arg0.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER)
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with your param, but if you're just looking for the params sent by the form, maybe you should try a Servlet Filter hook instead, so that you can intercept the call to a servlet and preprocess your request before the actual call.